# I have 2 different Azure subscription, Which needs to be transferred to Single Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, subscription, data-migration

For E.g I have two Azure Subscriptions. Subscription A and Subscription B and I need to Transfer the Subscription B to Subscription A. Is that possible to do the same? What approach do I need to use for this?

Do I need to Add Subscription B to A via Adding Azure active directory tenant registration? If yes then, I read a document that Subscription can only be added to a Single Azure Active directory? Then would be possible ?
Does Transferring ownership b/w both Azure account would work?

I have gone through multiple documents from Microsoft. 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/understanding-azure-account-subscription-and-directory/m-p/34800

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associate

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer an Azure subscription to another Azure subscription.

You can only transfer the ownership of the Azure susbcriptions to the same account.

Please refer to this document: [Transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer).

In fact, if you are not sure whether you can transfer the Azure subscription, you can open a subscription ticket by following [Open a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-troubleshooting-support-howto#open-a-support-ticket). The Azure Support will transfer the subscription for you.

Remember to choose **Subscription management** for **Issue type** on the **Basics** blade in step 3.

Subcription ticket is free to open.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I read some of the articles and came to know that we can add/assocaite new subscription into a existing Azure active directory.  PSB the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Comment: @MadhurAsati Yes. An Azure AD tenant can have multiple Azure subscriptions. If you just want to use the 2 subscriptions in your Azure AD, the link you shared is a good choice.

Comment: @MadhurAsati  My answer should also apply in this case. If it helps, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Once we add two different tenants into a single active directory can we migrate the data using change subscription option?

Comment: @MadhurAsati No. The data still exists under the corresponding subscription. If you want to migrate azure resource, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription.